# SQL: How do I count the number of clients that have already bought the same product?

Tags: sql, excel

I have a table like the one below.  It is a record of daily featured products and the customers that purchased them (similar to a daily deal site).  A given client can only purchase a product one time per feature, but they may purchase the same product if it is featured multiple times.

```
FeatureID | ClientID | FeatureDate | ProductID  
 1           1002      2011-05-01      500  
 1           2333      2011-05-01      500  
 1           4458      2011-05-01      500  
 2           8888      2011-05-10      700  
 2           2333      2011-05-10      700  
 2           1111      2011-05-10      700    
 3           1002      2011-05-20      500  
 3           4444      2011-05-20      500  
 4           4444      2011-05-30      500  
 4           2333      2011-05-30      500  
 4           1002      2011-05-30      500
```

**I want to count by FeatureID the number of clients that purchased FeatureID X AND who purchased the same productID during a previous feature.**

For the table above the expected result would be:

```
FeatureID | CountofReturningClients  
 1          0  
 2          0  
 3          1  
 4          3
```

Ideally I would like to do this with SQL, but am also open to doing some manipulation in Excel/PowerPivot.  Thanks!!

Comment: SQL onto Excel from what? Or from a database (which?) into Excel? In standard SQL it's simple enough...

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear on that, meant that if I had the raw data in Excel I would be open to feedback on how to get it into the format I was looking for.  But, you're right, the query is simple enough :)  Thanks everyone for all of the help!  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you join your table to itself, you can find the data you're looking for.  Be careful, because this query can take a long time if the table has a lot of data and is not indexed well.

```
SELECT t_current.FEATUREID, COUNT(DISTINCT t_prior.CLIENTID)
FROM table_name t_current
LEFT JOIN table_name t_prior
ON t_current.FEATUREDATE > t_prior.FEATUREDATE
AND t_current.CLIENTID = t_prior.CLIENTID
AND t_current.PRODUCTID = t_prior.PRODUCTID
GROUP BY t_current.FEATUREID
```

Answer (score 0):

"Per feature, count the clients who match for any earlier Features with the same product"

```
SELECT
   Curr.FeatureID
   COUNT(DISTINCT Prev.ClientID) AS CountofReturningClients --edit thanks to feedback
FROM
   MyTable Curr
   LEFT JOIN
   MyTable Prev WHERE Curr.FeatureID > Prev.FeatureID
                        AND Curr.ClientID = Prev.ClientID
                        AND Curr.ProductID = Prev.ProductID
GROUP BY
   Curr.FeatureID
```

Comment: You need to add a `DISTINCT` there - this will return 4 for feature 4 because it counts Client #1002 twice.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions: You have a table called Features that is:

FeatureID, FeatureDate, ProductID

If not then you could always create one on the fly with a temporary table, cte or view.

Then:

```
SELECT

FeatureID

, (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ClientID) FROM Purchases WHERE Purchases.FeatureDate < Feature.FeatureDate AND Feature.ProductID = Purchases.ProductID

) as CountOfReturningClients

FROM Features
ORDER BY FeatureID
```

Answer (score -1):

New to this, but wouldn't the following work?

```
SELECT     FeatureID, (CASE WHEN COUNT(clientid) > 1 THEN COUNT(clientid) ELSE 0 END)
FROM         table
GROUP BY featureID
```

Comment: That'll return the number of customers per feature, period. He wants the number of repeat customers per feature.